# TypeError: Cannot read property nodeName of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Elasticsearch and Node for Back-end application.
I'm trying to get Elastic response.but this error happen.

```
                uniqueid = (source[i]._source.uniqueid ? source[i]._source.uniqu
eid : source
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '_source' of undefined
```

source code :

```
var createArray = function(source, callback){
    this.source = source;
    var len = source.length;
    var eventDetails = [];
    var uniqueid;
    var i;
    for(i=0; i <= len ;i++)
    {

        uniqueid = (source[i]._source.uniqueid ? source[i]._source.uniqueid : source[i]._source.uniqueid1 );
        /....../
        eventDetails.push(uniqueid);
    }
    callback(eventDetails);
};
```

source array is something like this :

```
[
      {
        "_index": "tests",
        "_type": "Hangup",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "event": "Hangup",
          "privilege": "call,all",
          "channel": "SIP/102-000001aa<ZOMBIE>",
          "uniqueid": "14448293848.505",
          "calleridnum": "102",
          "calleridname": "Backup Reception",
          "connectedlinenum": "122",
          "connectedlinename": "someone eles",
          "accountcode": "",
          "cause": "16",
          "cause-txt": "Normal Clearing",
          "created": 1444829486490,
          "cnt": 22
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "tests",
        "_type": "Hangup",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "event": "Hangup",
          "privilege": "call,all",
          "channel": "SIP/121-000001b0",
          "uniqueid": "14448932858.518",
          "calleridnum": "121",
          "calleridname": "someone",
          "connectedlinenum": "<unknown>",
          "connectedlinename": "<unknown>",
          "accountcode": "",
          "cause": "16",
          "cause-txt": "Normal Clearing",
          "created": 1444892559309,
          "cnt": 26
        }
      }
    ]
```

I try this single line code and every thing works fine
this is it :

```
source[0]._source.uniqueid
```

Comment: `i` used out of bounds?

Comment: Your loop should be `i<len` and not `i<=len`.  For `i==len` you are out of bounds.

Comment: Yes. :) why can not use this `eventDetails[source[i]._source.cnt].push(uniqueid);`

Comment: the problem (as t.niese pointed out) is that if `source` array has 5 elements then they are `source[0]` to `source[4]`. If you use `i<=len` and len is 5 then the last iteration of the loop, where i == 5 means that `source[5]` is outside the bounds of the array and is undefined. So `source[i]` is undefined and `source[i]._source` cannot be read

Comment: short answer, do what he says and change  `i<=len` to  `i<len`   :)